# Search using date

Tags: django

Hello developers  can you please tell me how to search query objects by date for example if anybody want to search it will show me date picker and then i will choose  from 2019-3-11 to 2019-09-11 then it will print all results between these dates.. I am not looking for order by
dat = example.objects.all().order_by('-date'). Also i need template code for taking input .

```
models,py example
class Sample(models.Model):
    date = fields.DateField(auto_now=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First take `f_date` and `t_date` from your input field in `'2019-03-20'` format.

```
f_date = '2019-03-11'
t_date = '2019-09-11'

from_date = datetime.strptime(f_date, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
to_date = datetime.strptime(t_date, "%Y-%m-%d").date()

date_queryset = Sample.objects.filter(date__range=(from_date, date_date))
```

For detail [click here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#range)

Comment: I added in my answer

Comment: You ask for only django solution. If you need more help than you should also provide further information on the question of what you need

Comment: i forgot about that

Comment: Thanks for helping ok

Comment: Do you have any html template, any django view?

Comment: yeah but not for search bar.

Comment: where you need to search between two dates

Comment: ofc in template

Comment: ofc means what?